# Run JavaScript before redirect to other page

Tags: asp.net

I try to open a popup window with JavaScript before redirecting to another page.

I've written this code:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(Page), "abc", "window.open('http://yahoo.com','2','resizable=yes,directories= no,menubar=no,top=null,left=00, width=100,height=100')", true);
Response.Redirect(p.Url);
```

but it is only a redirect and a popup does not open.

How do I open a popup window before the user user redirects to another page?

Comment: As it stands, this kind of code will trigger the popup blocker of almost every browser because it was not popped up as part of user interaction (click in particular)

Comment: no probleam by brower block because test without redirect and opened popup windo

Comment: Just a small note, it's not javacode, nor "java script". It's javascript. You may think it's just a word play, but it may be really confusing when used badly... Java and javascript are two completely different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing anything like opening popup or window...before `response.redirect();` , it will not work. If you want to redirect to any page after opening pop up boxes, please ensure that redirection should be written in Javascript only not in C#

This will not work

```
Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('hello')</script>");  
Response.Redirect("About.aspx"); <br>
```

This will work

```
Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('hello');
window.location.href='About.aspx';</script>");
```

OR

```
if (!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("alert"))
{ 
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert",     "alertMe();window.location.href='About.aspx';", true);
}
```

In this way we can call External JS files also

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),    "callJS", 
 "&alt; script language='javascript' src='sample.js' &glt;  ");
```

Comment: I said use "window.location.href" And you said  "use window.location.href" ?? Wher is difference with my answer???? This very very very very ..... insteresting!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript you should insert your javascipt code to top of your aspx page(in `<head>` tags)

A working example for me;

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(Page), "abc", "<script>OpenWin();</script>", false);
Response.Redirect(p.Url);
```

In aspx head tags;

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function OpenWin() {
        window.open('http://yahoo.com', '2', 'resizable=yes,directories= no,menubar=no,top=null,left=00, width=100,height=100');
   }

</script>
```

If this code not works, another way;
You can use javascript for redirect. Like this ;

```
window.location.href="p.Url";
```

But on this way you should get p.Url value to javascript. You can do this a lot of way, (hiddenfield, session etc)